# Print each section that has more than n lines

Tags: awk

I have a file reshaping problem that I think can be done with a one-liner, but I'm a total newbie with sed and awk (and stack overflow also !). I'll surely lose my patience and do it in R but I think it could be interesting to have this kind of commands for later use.

I have a txt file with "clusters" that looks like this :

```
>Cluster 15425
0   1096aa, >d7719f16-11db-48c4-... *
>Cluster 15426
0   1096aa, >fd7eacf9-37cd-4b40-... *
1   436aa, >cfd4b1b0-30df-471e-... at 80.28%
2   413aa, >5992f56b-0269-4add-... at 86.68%
3   395aa, >d3be5814-b2e8-41fe-... at 89.37%
4   239aa, >9e25fbb9-9f6c-4f52-... at 80.33%
>Cluster 15427
0   1096aa, >6c8790d1-5a8b-42d4-... *
>Cluster 15428
0   1096aa, >0c00bc15-51aa-4676-... *
>Cluster 15429
0   1096aa, >1d8ab161-3aab-45a0-... *
>Cluster 15430
0   1096aa, >ef6694d2-a0e6-4bd1-... *
1   410aa, >313eee0a-e8c0-4e8c-... at 84.63%
```

It should be read like that :

cluster n°15425 has one item called >d7719f16-11db-48c4-...

cluster n°14426 has 5 items called >fd7eacf9-37cd-4b40-..., >cfd4b1b0-30df-471e-... etc up to >9e25fbb9-9f6c-4f52-...

What I want is to take that file as input, and spit out in another file all the clusters that have more than X items. Intuitively it should look for lines that start with ">" and print when the number of lines between these two lines is greater than X.

For X = 1, the output file should contain :

```
>Cluster 15426
0   1096aa, >fd7eacf9-37cd-4b40-... *
1   436aa, >cfd4b1b0-30df-471e-... at 80.28%
2   413aa, >5992f56b-0269-4add-... at 86.68%
3   395aa, >d3be5814-b2e8-41fe-... at 89.37%
4   239aa, >9e25fbb9-9f6c-4f52-... at 80.33%
>Cluster 15430
0   1096aa, >ef6694d2-a0e6-4bd1-... *
1   410aa, >313eee0a-e8c0-4e8c-... at 84.63%
```

(only clusters n°15426 and 15430 have more than one item)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Welcome to SO, sorry but your question is not clear. Could you please do add more details in your question about what are the conditions by which you want to get output file? Also is it 1 output file or multiple files which you need in output? Kindly do edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you for your comment, I edited the post. I want only one file as output, which is formated like the input file but without clusters of size = 1.
I also struggled to find a name for this post, if you have a better idea I would be happy. My difficulty to enunciate this issue is maybe why I've not found any help on google.

Comment: Slightly comical to think someone would regard R as the easier solution.

Answer (score 2):

Based on shown samples could you please try following, written and tested in GNU `awk`, reading Input_file 2 times here.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/^>/){
    ++count
    header[count]=$0
  }
  else{
    a[count]++
    b[count]=(b[count]?b[count] ORS:"")$0
  }
  next
}
/^>/ && a[++count1]>1{
  print header[count1] ORS b[count1]
}
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                           ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                        ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first time Input_file is being read.
  if($0~/^>/){                                  ##Checking condition if line starts from ^then do following.
    ++count                                     ##Increment 1 with count here.
    header[count]=$0                            ##Creating header array with index of count and its value is current line.
  }
  else{                                         ##mentioning else of above here.
    a[count]++                                  ##Creating array a with index of count and keep increasing its value with 1.
    b[count]=(b[count]?b[count] ORS:"")$0       ##Creating array b with index of count and keep concatenating its values with new line here.
  }
  next                                          ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^>/ && a[++count1]>1{                          ##Checking condition if line starts from > AND value of array a with index of count1 is greater than 1 then do following.
  print header[count1] ORS b[count1]            ##Printing header with index count1 and array b with index of count1 here.
}
'  Input_file Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`, requires multi-char RS support (e.g. gawk).

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS='\n>' 'NF>2{printf "%s", rt $0} {rt=RT}' file

>Cluster 15426
0   1096aa, >fd7eacf9-37cd-4b40-... *
1   436aa, >cfd4b1b0-30df-471e-... at 80.28%
2   413aa, >5992f56b-0269-4add-... at 86.68%
3   395aa, >d3be5814-b2e8-41fe-... at 89.37%
4   239aa, >9e25fbb9-9f6c-4f52-... at 80.33%
>Cluster 15430
0   1096aa, >ef6694d2-a0e6-4bd1-... *
1   410aa, >313eee0a-e8c0-4e8c-... at 84.63%
```

it can be simplified

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS='\n>' 'NF>2{print ">" $0}' file
```

note that there is an extra new line, at the beginning in the first option and at the end in the second.

Comment: Thank you !! I new that this kind of commands could exist, I'll keep it in my "magic commands" file :) I'll try do dissect it later.

Comment: If you change the last block in the file to be 1 line instead of 2 that script will still output it as if it satisfied the "more than 1 line" criteria. I thought changing the `RS` to `\n(>|$)` would fix it and it does solve that problem but then it introduces another problem with no terminating `\n` in the output.

Answer (score 1):

The following `perl` solution works.

```
perl -ne '
    BEGIN { $N = 1 }
    if (/^>/) {
        print @b if @b > $N+1;
        @b = ();
    }
    push @b, $_;
    END {
        print @b if @b > $N+1
    }' input_file
```

An `awk` solution that uses the same method:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { N = 1 }
    /^>/ {
        if (nb>N+1) for (i=0; i<nb; i++) print b[i];
        nb = 0; delete b;
    }
    { b[nb++]= $0; }
    END {
        if (nb>N+1) for (i=0; i<nb; i++) print b[i];
    }' input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^>/ { prt() }
{ rec = (cnt++ ? rec ORS : "") $0 }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if ( cnt > (x+1) ) {
        print rec
    }
    rec = cnt = ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v x=1 -f tst.awk file
>Cluster 15426
0   1096aa, >fd7eacf9-37cd-4b40-... *
1   436aa, >cfd4b1b0-30df-471e-... at 80.28%
2   413aa, >5992f56b-0269-4add-... at 86.68%
3   395aa, >d3be5814-b2e8-41fe-... at 89.37%
4   239aa, >9e25fbb9-9f6c-4f52-... at 80.33%
>Cluster 15430
0   1096aa, >ef6694d2-a0e6-4bd1-... *
1   410aa, >313eee0a-e8c0-4e8c-... at 84.63%
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide any script, so I won't provide you with a complete answer, but I might give you a start: in order to count the number of lines of a file, you can use `wc -l`:

```
wc -l file.txt
12 file.txt
```

You might use `awk` for having only the first part of the result (the number of lines).

If you are interested in the number of lines, obeying a certain condition, you might work with a combination of `grep` and `wc -l`:

```
grep <something> file.txt | wc -l
3
```

(In case, obviously, that there are three times `<something>` in file.txt)

This gives you a head start for your script.